# How to wrap the selected text with an open and close tag?

Tags: text, keyboard-shortcuts, aptana

I thought there was a shortcut available to wrap the selected text with an open and close tag, in Aptana. I believe it was <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>.

This now closes out the file. Is this shortcut not available any more? Is there an alternative available?

Comment: What editor, os, typewriter are you using?

Comment: Sorry forgot to clarify: Aptana 3 on Windows 7

Answer (score 5):

No solution with shortcut (yet) but you can prevent closing all tabs by mistake.

Open 'Window' > 'Preferences' and choose 'General' > 'Keys'. Find the command "Close All" and select this command with the binding "Ctrl+Shift+w" and click the button [Unbind Command]. This at least does not close all your tabs when you accidentally hit Ctrl+Shift+w...

Open 'Commands' > 'HTML' and you are able to select "Wrap Selection in Open/Close Tag". Maybe this shortcut only works when editing .htm(l) files... I will look into this.

I assume we should be able to bind this shortcut to the command to wrap tags around selected text, but I haven't found that command (yet, hopefully). It is restricted to HTML bundle?

Comment: once you've unbound the Close All command, the default wrap will take effect.  it is already set as Ctrl+Shift+W and works perfectly.

Comment: I'm running ubuntu under windows. I found that I need to use the left side CTRL and SHIFT with the W.. That is a little awkward. The right side keys don't seem to work. @WhiteRau - thanks you are correct in that it works when the close is unbound